# Open about:blank window in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

When i open a new window using window.open javascript, chrome opens with about:blank, but firefox opens with jsfiddle back url and if you right click on the page, you can still see the page loading. You will not see the refresh icon, instead a stop icon is appearing.

I need to open the new window with about:blank.

Here is the [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/rs8f3fzd/1/)

Tested with Chrome 45.0
Tested with Firefox 41.1

```
<button id="helper">Click here for help</button>
```

Comment: No..it didnt work. _blank is for fullscreen right

Comment: Sorry, misread your question

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't allow `document.write`

Comment: After `openedDocument.write(myHTML)` you should close the document with `openedDocument.close()`.

Comment: Mr.Oriol, it solved half of my problem. Thanks.Can you post this as a answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are experiencing is a new Firefox behavior that passed in version 40 or 41 (sorry I did not find the reference).

Expect it to become part of google's behavior soon too, you can see people requesting it already([Chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=466422&q=label%3ACr-Security&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&start=200))

Unfortunately there is not much that can be done for now as it is brand new people have not found workaround or even if it is a good idea to fight against the browser... My suggestion is to not use about:blank at all and use a blank html page from your domain, that would make things easier on the users.

Comment: Appreciable feedback. Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `about:blank` take `#`:

```
 $("#helper").click(function(){
                  windowURL = window.open("#","Looking ....
```

**EDIT**

in order to prevent the browser from showing an "infinite loading", close the document:

```
...
openedDocument.open();
openedDocument.write(myHTML)
openedDocument.close()
```

Comment: And what IS happening? It works for me in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Are you getting about:blank in FF. ? I rechecked it ...its not in my ff.... Did the page loading stopped.

Comment: I get a new window with the text in it

Comment: Its not the text. its the url address bar it keeps on reloading... right click on the opened page. you will see a cross icon not the refresh icon.which means the page is infinitely loading.